# I am trying to get Fibonacci series using recursion using 3 arguments it only gives 0000..values not incrementing

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h
void fibo(int n ,int a ,int b)
{
        int n1=0,n2=1,ele=0;
        if(n>=1){
                printf(" %d",n1);
                ele=n1+n2;
                n1=n2;
                n2=ele;
        }
        fibo(n-1,n1,n2);
}


int main(){

        fibo(10,0,1);

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `n1` is always *zero* when printed. I suggest learning how to use a *debugger.*

Comment: Okay, now that it's formatted... you never even use the arguments passed in. Where are `a` and `b` used?  What are they supposed to be?

Comment: By the way , you are not anywhere using the parameteres `a` and `b` in `fibo()`

Comment: `int n1=a, n2=b` will do (partly) the trick, revise the recursion and the end condition

Comment: The code you are showing has a syntax error: `#include <stdio.h`. And where's the return value for `fibo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.  First you don't initialize your local variables in the `fibo` function properly.  So, your variable declarations should be:

```
 int n1=a,n2=b,ele=0;
```

Also, you never stop the recursion you just keep calling fibo with a decremented value of n.  So, add an else to your if clause to return when `n < 1`.

Comment: instead of an else clause, couldn't he just put the recursive call into the if clause?